# How does angular2-component know it's active when restored by RouteReuseStrategy?

Tags: angular

I have a component MainPageComponent. When user clicks "Main page" from the top menu, my custom RouteReuseStrategy restores the "Main page"-route from the memory and users picks off where he left. How can I know in the code of this restored component when it's being restored and back alive?

I assume ngOnInit isn't called because this isn't the component init, but it's already up and running. Is there some method that's being called on the component on restore by RouteReuseStrategy?

I don't know if relevant, but here's the custom RouteReuseStrategy component I use. The route for the "Main page" in this would be in the routesToStore-array - those routes are restored from memory upon request.

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouteReuseStrategy, DetachedRouteHandle } from '@angular/router';

interface RouteStorageObject {
    snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
    handle: DetachedRouteHandle;
}

export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
    constructor() {
        // Determine which routes to preserve
        this.routesToStore = ["search", "favorites", "explore"];
    }

    routesToStore: string[];
    storedRoutes: { [key: string]: RouteStorageObject } = {}

    // If returns false, user is let to leave current view
    shouldReuseRoute (future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        // Return false if navigating to another route than current
        return future.routeConfig === current.routeConfig;
    }

    // Should the route be stored?
    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        // Keep state of all routes by always returning true
        if (this.routesToStore.indexOf(route.routeConfig.path) > -1)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        let storedRoute: RouteStorageObject = {
            snapshot: route,
            handle: handle
        };

        this.storedRoutes[route.routeConfig.path] = storedRoute;
    }

    // Should the component state be restored?
    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        // If the route has been stored before
        let canAttach: boolean = !!route.routeConfig && !!this.storedRoutes[route.routeConfig.path];

        if (canAttach)
            return true;

        return false;        
    }

    // Retrieve the component state
    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {

        if (!route.routeConfig || !this.storedRoutes[route.routeConfig.path]) return null;

        return this.storedRoutes[route.routeConfig.path].handle;

    }
}
```

Comment: when a component is activated you will have lifecycle hooks like `ngDoCheck` triggered for the componnent

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I tried this, but the problem is I only need to do the things once upon view "re-init". If I put stuff to ngDoCheck, then it's called constantly when the view is active. If I would use some boolean to know when the view has been "re-initialized", then I would need to also know when it's being deactivated (but stored). Is there a way to do this? Lifecycle hooks contained AfterContentInit and those, but they weren't called upon view restore. Only ngDoCheck seemed to be. Can the RouteReuseStrategy someone notify the view it's been restored?

Comment: sorry. don't know

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519512/angular2-routereusestrategy-lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2+ routeReuseStrategy lifecycle hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519512/angular2-routereusestrategy-lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`(activate)`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) event on `<router-outlet>`.

https://netbasal.com/angular-2-router-routeroutlet-events-8b0803d88082

So handle the event in your `app.component.html` page :

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

And in your `app.component.ts`:

```
// yes - the $event is the component itself 
onActivate(component)
{
    if (component["onActivate"])
    {
        component.onActivate();
    }

    // [optional] tell your shared service 
    this.pageManagerService.activeComponent.next(component);
}
```

I created a simple page manager service, that is informed when a new component is activated. This is shared so I can inject it wherever I want. It controls things like how the menu appears based on the current component, background color of the page etc.

(Similar idea to the question pointed to by @Su-Au Hwang)

Comment: This doesn't work for the OP. The (activate) is only triggered once, and not triggered when the route is restored by RouteReuseStrategy.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround (until RouteReuseStrategy is enhanced with a proper hook to support this situation) is to listen to NavigationEnd in the component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url == thisUrl) {
      // route is restored
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `(attach)` event on the `router-outlet`: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#attach

From the docs:

> Called when the `RouteReuseStrategy` instructs to re-attach a previously detached subtree.

```
<router-outlet (attach)="onAttach($event)"></router-outlet>
```

And in your component containing the `router-outlet` you can implement what should happen when the component is re-attached to the component tree.

```
onAttach(component) {
    // do your custom logic here, e.g. trigger some method on the re-attached component
}
```